# Input type hidden passing only last value of foreach loop

Tags: php, html, input, html-table, hidden

I have a foreach and a table and im trying to send the id of the specific row when button pressed, but its always sending the data of the last row in the input type hidden "solicitudId" id. At the "input type hidden animales[]" is passing all the elements, not the elements of the selected row.
`

```
<?php if (isset($solis) && !empty($solis)) { ?>

                    <thead>

                        <th>Opcion</th>
                        <th>Nombre Dueño</th>
                        <th>Nombre Guardian</th>
                        <th>Desde</th>
                        <th>Hasta</th>
                        <th>Direccion de guarda</th>
                        <th>Nombre de mascota</th>
                        <th>Especie</th>
                        <th>Raza</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php if ($_SESSION['tipo'] == 'g') { ?>
                            <form action="<?php echo FRONT_ROOT ?>Guardian/operarSolicitud" method="POST">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <form action="<?php echo FRONT_ROOT ?>Dueno/cancelarSolicitud" method="POST">
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php foreach ($solis as $solicitud) {
                                    $count = 0;
                                ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($mascXsoli as $tabla) { 
                                        if ($tabla->getIdSolicitud() == $solicitud->getId()) {
                                            $idMascotaX = $tabla->getIdMascota();
                                            foreach ($mascotas as $masc) {
                                                if ($masc->getId() == $idMascotaX) {
                                                    $count++;
                                                }
                                            } //contar para hacer el rowspan
                                        }
                                    } ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td rowspan="<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="solicitudId" value="<?php echo $solicitud->getId(); ?>">
                                            <?php if ($_SESSION['tipo'] == 'g') { ?>
                                                <button type="submit" name="operacion" value="aceptar" class="btn btn-danger"> Aceptar </button>
                                                <button type="submit" name="operacion" value="rechazar" class="btn btn-danger"> Rechazar </button>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Cancelar </button>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td rowspan="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $solicitud->getNombreDueno(); ?></td>
                                        <td rowspan="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $solicitud->getNombreGuardian(); ?></td>
                                        <td rowspan="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $solicitud->getFechaInicio(); ?></td>
                                        <td rowspan="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $solicitud->getFechaFin(); ?></td>
                                        <td rowspan="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $solicitud->getDireccionGuardian(); ?></td>


                                        <?php foreach ($mascXsoli as $tabla) {
                                            if ($tabla->getIdSolicitud() == $solicitud->getId()) {
                                                $idMascotaX = $tabla->getIdMascota();
                                                foreach ($mascotas as $masc) {
                                                    if ($masc->getId() == $idMascotaX) { ?>

                                                        <td><?php echo $masc->getNombre(); ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $masc->getEspecie(); ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $masc->getRaza(); ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $masc->getObservaciones(); ?></td> <? //TAMAÑO Y FOTOS 
                                                                                                            ?>
                                                        <?php if ($_SESSION['tipo'] == 'g') { ?>
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="animales[]" value="<?php echo $masc->getId(); ?>">
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </tr>
            <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo " <h4>NO HAY SOLICITUDES ENVIADAS!</h4>";
                                    ?>
                                Si ha enviado una solicitud anteriormente, puede que esta haya sido aceptada y
                                deba pagar su confirmacion.
                                <?php  } ?>
```

`

I use this structure in a lot of views, and all have the same problem.

Comment: I think you forgot to close your form tag and that's why when submit is pressed all data in the page is being sent since ```</form>``` can not be found

Comment: Make a separate form for each `solicitud` entity.